# HttpStatusCode.NotFound is giving error now c#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a code for checking if response is error 404 an if it is set an image from resources that code works fine before but now it is giving error I don't know why. Here is the code

```
 try
        {
            picture.Load(img);
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            HttpWebResponse errorResponse = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Image image = Properties.Resources.Error_404;
                picture.Image = image;
            }
        }
```

the HttpStatusCode,NotFound is what gives error Object reference not set to an instance of an object C#.

Comment: No, `HttpStatusCode.NotFound` will *not* give that error... but `errorResponse.StatusCode` certainly will, if `errorResponse` is null, which it will be if `we.Response` isn't an `HttpWebResponse`. *Any* time you use `as`, you need to consider what you want to happen if the result is `null`.

Comment: Check for errorResponse object as well. if (errorResponse == null || errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)

Comment: but it was working fine before for the same request and now it is giving this error. :/

Comment: Can't you debug and check which object is null?

Comment: @kashi_rock it works if(errorResponse == null || errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound). Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Please post your own answer and mark as answered

Comment: I don't know how to do that.